# to get past a press law

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can you help me about the exact meaning of the following passage?

> Homayoon, himself an eminent journalist, had worked to get past a press law to balance the press freedom with responsibility—in vain, as events evolved.

The phrase "get past" is especially problematic. Does it mean to pass a law, or skip a law?

Comment: laws are **passed**, not past. So, you can take "to pass a law" out of the running.

Comment: Who wrote this? From the limited context we have, it sounds as though the intended meaning might have been *passed* ... but then it should be *to get a press law passed*, and it seems implausible that someone would make such a big mistake.

Comment: In the context of the rest of that sentence I think they mean "passed".

Comment: No, **to get past something is an idiom**. It means to avoid it or go beyond it or overcome it.  To get past a barrier, to get past one's feelings, to get past whatever.

Answer (score 2):

*Get past a law* can (and I think here does) mean to avoid the applicability of a law. For example, if the law dictates that that one may not drive in a certain lane if alone (but with a non-driving passenger it's okay), putting a passenger in the car solely for the purpose of being able to drive in that lane can be called *getting past the law*. *Press law* here seems to mean a law that affects the press, meaning journalists and the like. I suspect therefore that the sentence means: Homayoon, himself an eminent journalist, had tried to evade the applicability of a law imposed on members of the press that required them to balance their freedom with responsibility—in vain, as events evolved.